# Mistery of Iterators

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, iterator

I'm going crazy for the strange behaviour of the Iterators in Google Apps Script.
My script picks a random folder (corresponding to a year between 2012 and the current year), then pick a random image in. The file's random criterion is a led by a random integer which stops the loop at the integer-th iteration.
It works, the debug and the script silently execute. But, but, but: **the photo-rolling rendering of the script deliveries always the same 4-5 pictures**. They are thousands.
I control the caching, also the F12 function tabs says the cache is null and Ctrl+F5 does not any positive effect.
Then, I ask the script to log the URL of the image. Surprise: **even if the random number that enters the if-statement is different, however the resulting URL is the same**. By chance, the folder is the same, but the different random numbers get the same image picked.
HELP!
[image]

```js
function doGet() {
  var folderImmagini_ID ="myID";
  //---
  // picking year folder between 2012 and current year
  var annoCorrente = new Date().getFullYear();
  var numFolderRandom = Math.random() * (annoCorrente - 2011) + 1;
  var nomeFolderRandom = (numFolderRandom + 2011).toString();
  var nomeFolderFinale = nomeFolderRandom.substring(0, nomeFolderRandom.indexOf("."));
  // once get random folder, picking a random image
  var foldersIterator = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderImmagini_ID).getFolders();
  var nomeCartella, cartella;
  while (foldersIterator.hasNext()) {
    cartella = foldersIterator.next(),
    nomeCartella = cartella.getName();
    if (nomeCartella == nomeFolderFinale) {
      var filesIterator = cartella.getFiles();
      var numeroFiles = 0, file;
      while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
        numeroFiles = numeroFiles + 1;
        file = filesIterator.next();
      }
      var numFileRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * numeroFiles) + 1;
      var ordineFile = 0;
      filesIterator = cartella.getFiles();
      while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
        ordineFile = ordineFile + 1;
        if (ordineFile == numFileRandom) {
          var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('OutputHTML');
          var foto = filesIterator.next();
          t.fotoID = foto.getId();
                         Logger.log("nome folder: %s, numero random: %s, link foto: %s",nomeCartella, numFileRandom, 
                                    "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id="+ t.fotoID);
          return t.evaluate();
        }
      }
    }   
  }
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <center><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=<?= fotoID ?>" height="85%" width="85%"></center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

When I saw your showing script, it seems that `var foto = filesIterator.next();` is used in the if-statement of `if (ordineFile == numFileRandom) {,,,}`. In this case, when `ordineFile == numFileRandom` is true, `var foto = filesIterator.next();` is used for the first time. In this case, I'm worried that `ordineFile = ordineFile + 1;` is not used for selecting the file. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue.

If you want to modify your showing script, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
  ordineFile = ordineFile + 1;
  if (ordineFile == numFileRandom) {
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('OutputHTML');
    var foto = filesIterator.next(); // <--- here
    t.fotoID = foto.getId();
    Logger.log("nome folder: %s, numero random: %s, link foto: %s", nomeCartella, numFileRandom,
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + t.fotoID);
    return t.evaluate();
  }
}
```

#### To:

```
while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
  ordineFile = ordineFile + 1;
  var foto = filesIterator.next(); // <--- here
  if (ordineFile == numFileRandom) {
    var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('OutputHTML');
    t.fotoID = foto.getId();
    Logger.log("nome folder: %s, numero random: %s, link foto: %s", nomeCartella, numFileRandom,
      "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + t.fotoID);
    return t.evaluate();
  }
}
```

- In this case, `var foto = filesIterator.next();` was moved outside of the if-statement of `if (ordineFile == numFileRandom) {,,,}`.

#### Note:

- As another approach, I thought that the file is randomly selected from the file ID list. In this case, how about the following modification?

  ```js
  function doGet() {
    var folderImmagini_ID = "myID";
    //---
    // picking year folder between 2012 and current year
    var annoCorrente = new Date().getFullYear();
    var numFolderRandom = Math.random() * (annoCorrente - 2011) + 1;
    var nomeFolderRandom = (numFolderRandom + 2011).toString();
    var nomeFolderFinale = nomeFolderRandom.substring(0, nomeFolderRandom.indexOf("."));
    // once get random folder, picking a random image
    var foldersIterator = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderImmagini_ID).getFolders();
    var nomeCartella, cartella;

    // I modified the below script.
    while (foldersIterator.hasNext()) {
      cartella = foldersIterator.next(), nomeCartella = cartella.getName();
      if (nomeCartella == nomeFolderFinale) {
        var filesIterator = cartella.getFiles();
        var fileIds = [];
        while (filesIterator.hasNext()) {
          fileIds.push(filesIterator.next().getId());
        }
        var numFileRandom = Math.floor(Math.random() * fileIds.length);
        var t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('OutputHTML');
        t.fotoID = fileIds[numFileRandom];
        Logger.log("nome folder: %s, numero random: %s, link foto: %s", nomeCartella, numFileRandom + 1, "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=" + t.fotoID);
        return t.evaluate();
      }
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: I shall try script with the "extraction" of the next() iterated file.

Comment: About randomly selecting an ID, it is truly an elegant solution, and I suspect it is a little bit faster in terms of machine-time.

Comment: "I shall try script with the "extraction" of the next() iterated file." cont'd: However, I am afraid that if it successed it would be due to the compilation routine, since from a alghoritmic point of view the place of the next() seems to be the rigth place.

Comment: Thank you for replying. If my answer was not useful, I apologize. About `About randomly selecting an ID, it is truly an elegant solution, and I suspect it is a little bit faster in terms of machine-time.`, also I think that it's yes. About `However, I am afraid that if it successed it would due to the compilation routine, since from a alghoritmic point of view the place of the next() seems to be the rigth place.`, I cannot understand it. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I do not know if your english is poor or better than mine, but you are right on the position of the .next() statement. Bottom line: it finally works.

Comment: @Gabriele Welcome. Thank you for letting me know. I'm glad your issue was resolved. If your question was solved, please push an accept button. Other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. And I think that your issue and solution will be useful for them. If you don't find the button, feel free to tell me. https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Gabriele Thank you for your response. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.